# Why angular 2 "Filters" are called "Pipe"?

Tags: angularjs, angular

In [Angular 1](https://angularjs.org/), when we want to format the value of an expression for display to the user we use angular [Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). In [Angular 2](http://angular.io), We use [Pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) for the same.

**Angular 1 Filters:**

HTML:

```
<p> {{ greetings | reverse }}</p>
```

Js:

```
app.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(input, uppercase) {
    input = input || '';
    var out = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      out = input.charAt(i) + out;
    }
    // conditional based on optional argument
    if (uppercase) {
      out = out.toUpperCase();
    }
    return out;
  };
});
```

**Angular 2**:

HTML:

```
<p> {{ greetings | reverse }}</p>
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'reverse'})
export class ReversePipe {
  transform(input:string): string {
    input = input || '';
    let out = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      out = input.charAt(i) + out;
    }
    return out;
  }
}
```

By looking at code, one can conclude that both does the same thing. Both have same roles and responsibility. What I want to know is **Why they are renamed to Pipe in Angular 2?**

Comment: So, You want to know what is `pipe`?

Comment: It is because of the ' | ' operator which is know as pipe.The name came from the operator name .

Comment: But pipe operator was with filters also... Why down vote? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Pipe has a more general meaning and is used not only for filtering.

You may also want to read the paragraph from [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe-) about why `filter` is absent in Angular 2:

> Angular does not ship with pipes for filtering or sorting lists.
>   Developers familiar with Angular 1 know these as filter and orderBy.
>   There are no equivalents in Angular 2.
>
> This is not an oversight. Angular 2 is unlikely to offer such pipes
>   because (a) they perform poorly and (b) they prevent aggressive
>   minification. Both filter and orderBy require parameters that
>   reference object properties. We learned earlier that such pipes must
>   be impure and that Angular calls impure pipes in almost every change
>   detection cycle.
>
> Filtering and especially sorting are expensive operations. The user
>   experience can degrade severely for even moderate sized lists when
>   Angular calls these pipe methods many times per second. The filter and
>   orderBy have often been abused in Angular 1 apps, leading to
>   complaints that Angular itself is slow. That charge is fair in the
>   indirect sense that Angular 1 prepared this performance trap by
>   offering filter and orderBy in the first place.